# Running XUnit.net Tests with TestDriven.net

Tags: xunit.net, testdriven.net

I've used NUnit for years and I wanted to try XUnit.  So I installed XUnit and ran the executable that allowed you to run XUnit via TD.net.

I can't seem to run more than one test at a time. With NUnit + TD.net, I could click on the filename in the solution and run all the tests in the file.  I can't seem to do that with XUnit + TD.net.

Is this something I can do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you run the installer that comes with XUnit.net.
There is a button to click that will install the TestDriven.net support.

The problem you are having is described here:
http://www.codeplex.com/xunit/Wiki/View.aspx?title=FaqTestDrivenNet&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 8):

Short Answer: Copy the following into a .reg file on your computer, updating the path to where your Xunit dll resides, and then import it into your registry.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MutantDesign\TestDriven.NET\TestRunners\xunit] @="4"
>   "AssemblyPath"="C:\_Files\Programs\Programming\XUnit\xunit-1.1.0\xunit.runner.tdnet.dll"
>   "TypeName"="Xunit.Runner.TdNet.TdNetRunner"

Long Answer:

I've run into this problem a couple of times, both on 32 and 64 bit versions of windows. TestDriven.net uses the registry to store a list of test frameworks avaialable. XUnit comes with an installer xunit.installer (run as admin) which is supposed to make the correct registry entries.

Usually I can get TD.net to work with XUnit for awhile, then I loose support. Today I was trying to get it to work on Windows 7 beta for the first time and couldn't get it to work at all.

After some searching I found the registry key that the information about the test framework should be entered in.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MutantDesign\TestDriven.NET\TestRunners

Now on 64bit systems, there is also a key under the Wow6432Node, which is where it looks like the Xunit installer was setting the registry key.

Anyway, I exported the the the xunit registry key from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MutantDesign\TestDriven.NET\TestRunners\xunit and, edited it, removing the Wow6432Node and then imported it. After restarting visual studio, everything works. I'll keep the registry file around in case it breaks again.